# Value and variant type of "#N/A"?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to figure out what does `#N/A` represent in VBA.

What I got so far is this `Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA`

I tried applying it on my macro but it's not working.

What I'm trying to make is an if statement with a condition to find cells with `#N/A` value.

What I wanna do is like this:

```
Dim MyCell As Range

For Each MyCell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")
   If ActiveSheet.Range("C" & MyCell.Row).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA Then
      'do something
   End If
Next
```

But the thing is, (1) it does not work, (2) program/macro halts when it encounters `#N/A` value.

Comment: I imagine you would need to call ISNA like so If  Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ActiveSheet.Range("C" & MyCell.Row).Value) Then.

Comment: logical but I really can test it as the second problem still occurs. @99moorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the function wrong. [See here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isna.php) for more information about ISNA.

Instead try:

```
Dim MyCell As Range

For Each MyCell In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ActiveSheet.Range("C" & MyCell.Row)) = True Then
  'do something
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to test for a specific error type, a simpler way is to use IsError:

```
If IsError(ActiveSheet.Range("C" & MyCell.Row).Value) then
```

Comment: Plus one, nice and simple.

Answer (score 0):

`#N/A` is modelled by a `variant` set to an error type with value `xlErrNA`.

`ActiveSheet.Range("C" & MyCell.Row).Value = CVErr(xlErrNA)` will work.

You might need to check the type of the left hand side first to avoid type mismatches in general cases.

`If VarType(ActiveSheet.Range("C" & MyCell.Row).Value) = vbError Then`

Comment: Just for my own learning what does VarType do? convert it to Var?

Comment: It tells you the type of a variant: e.g. double, integer, string, error, etc.

Comment: Ah now that is handy to know!

Comment: I tried it but still gives me the mismatched error. @Bathsheba

Comment: Only call the line containing ` = CVErr` if the variant is an error type.